# Remap the columns value to column name in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```py
data = [{'model': 'v1', 'data': [1, 2, 3, 4]}]
data = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
```

its value is

```
    model   data
0   V1      [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I want answer like this :

```
      V1 
0     [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: There is only one row in DataFrame? If 2 or more rows what is logic for output ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html)

If the output you desire is

```
                  0
model            v1
data   [1, 2, 3, 4]
```